# "Principal" attribute in "AWS::SQS::QueuePolicy" is not taking in AWS ARN

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have created SNS and SQS with CloudFormantion in different accounts and was able to subscribe to SNS, able to receive messages, working as expected. Code used:

CF in Account-02:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
    Resources:
        Queue:
        Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
        Properties:
            QueueName: "SampleQueue"
        SqsQueuePolicy:
        Type: AWS::SQS::QueuePolicy
        Properties:
            PolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Id: MyQueuePolicy
            Statement:
                - Sid: Allow-SNS-SendMessage
                Effect: Allow
                Principal: "*"
                Action:
                    - sqs:SendMessage
                Resource: !GetAtt Queue.Arn
                Condition:
                    ArnEquals:
                    aws:SourceArn: "arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:<account-01>:SampleTopic"
            Queues:
            - !Ref Queue
    
        SnsSubscription:
        Type: AWS::SNS::Subscription
        Properties:
            Protocol: sqs
            Endpoint: !GetAtt Queue.Arn
            Region: "eu-west-1"

            TopicArn: "arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:<account-01>:SampleTopic"
```

When Principal is set as below, it doesn't work(no messages are received to SQS). Anything wrong in it?

```
Principal:
    AWS:
      - arn:aws:iam::<account-02>:user/user01
```

It also works expected with "SQS::QueuePolicy" Principal as below:

```
Principal:
    Service:
      - sns.amazonaws.com
```

Want to check why Principal is not taking a valid AWS ARN?

(yes, the Condition element in the Policy is restrictive enough, other topics cannot post to the queue, but our security team is not happy with this...want to understand why Principal is not taking in a valid one? )

Comment: What other possibilities? Who do you want to allow to send messages to the topic? Do you have a principal for that? Then add that principal in the policy. Can your so-called security team be more specific in what they do not like and propose an alternative?

Comment: *"Ideally would like to restrict to AWS user/role."* - you are, you are restricting it to an AWS service / service role.

Comment: @luk2302 tried by adding the Principal, then cannot receive the msgs to SQS

Comment: Well, `arn:aws:iam::<account-02>:user/user01` do not send the message, do they. The message is sent by .... sns.amazonaws.com